# Shopify public app with MVC views not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, shopify, shopify-app

Simple .net MVC app. After installing my app I see the welcome screen (embedded) within the Shopify admin panel. For some reason Shopify will NOT load any View that contains a `<form>` tag

```
<form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Account" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 ... blah blah blah 
</form>
```

How can I make this work with Views that have forms?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it like this works:

```
<form action="/Account/Login" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```